# unzip nested dictionary in function to calculate dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have different nested dictionaries, want to calculate discount wise score

```
A = {'tr_1': {'hos': 100.0, 'dy': 100.0},
 'tr_2': {'hos': 100.0, 'dy': 50.0},
 'tr_3': {'hos': 100.0, 'dy': 50.0}}

B = {'tr_1': {'cor': 160, 'ner': 0},
 'tr_2': {'cor': 69, 'ner': 36.14},
 'tr_3': {'cor': 63, 'ner': 41.69}}

c = {'tr_1': {'st': 0, 'st_c': 100.0},
 'tr_2': {'st': 1368, 'st_c': 0},
 'tr_3': {'st': 1366, 'st_c': 0}}
```

Below code is for single discount.
I want to do this calculation for each trip
want to save in another dictionary

```
dis = {}
A = {'dy':18}
B = {'ner':89}
C = {'st_c':56}
eff = (
        (20 * A['dy']) 
        +
        (20 * B['ner']) 
        +
        (20 * C['st_c'])
dis['value'] = eff
```

expected output like be:

```
dis = {'tr_1': {'eff':32},
'tr_2': {'eff':45},
'tr_3': {'eff':23}}
```

how to do that?
Not required to multiply each nested dict in the last
as you can see in the screenshot
adding screenshot of expected but want in dict
[image]

column eff be like

```
dd = {'tr1': {'eff':40},
'tr2':{'eff':360},
'tr3':{'eff':410}
```

Comment: Not sure how you calculate 32/45/23, 2 digits numbers multiplied by 20, you should be in the range of hundreds to thousands.

Comment: @mozway where i multiplied 20 it is for single, added only for understanding..

Comment: So is my proposed code below what you want (maybe without the multiplication by 20)?

Comment: @mozway added screenshot.. may this help.

Comment: How is `100*0*100` equal to `200`?

Comment: @mozway sry for this. messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
import math

dicts = [A, B, C]
keys = ['dy', 'ner', 'st_c']

out = {k: {'eff': round(0.2*math.prod(d[k][k2] for k2,d in zip(keys, dicts)), 2)}
       for k in A}

print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'tr_1': {'eff': 9.0},
 'tr_2': {'eff': 54.0},
 'tr_3': {'eff': 44.8}}
```

Used input:

```
A = {'tr_1': {'hos': 100.0, 'dy': 3},
     'tr_2': {'hos': 100.0, 'dy': 9},
     'tr_3': {'hos': 100.0, 'dy': 4}}

B = {'tr_1': {'cor': 160, 'ner': 5},
     'tr_2': {'cor': 69, 'ner': 6},
     'tr_3': {'cor': 63, 'ner': 8}}

C = {'tr_1': {'st': 0, 'st_c': 3},
     'tr_2': {'st': 1368, 'st_c': 5},
     'tr_3': {'st': 1366, 'st_c': 7}}
```